# how to cancel keyboard P key, shortcuts to changing resolution on gnome through NX (nomachine)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome, vnc, nx, nomachine

I don't know why, but suddenly, after connecting to a gnome-session through NX, every time when I press (lower case) p, the session changes resolution (instead of just printing 'p' on the screen).

Any idea how to revert it?

Notes:

1. Reconnecting to the session didn't help.
2. I am not a superuser on the NX server
3. I am a superuser on the NX client
4. Yesterday I've used xrandr on the remote to change the resolution. However, everything was fine until an hour ago.

EDIT: I have connected to the session from a client on a different computer, and the issue persists. So I suspect it is related to the gnome session

Thank you!

Comment: Try pressing the shift key 4-5 times in a row, same for ctrl, alt, tab, and the windows key. No idea why but this has fixed weird key behaviours for me before. Be amazed. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was simple:
Log out from the gnome session and log-in (a new session).